# Installation Issue Error 500

Tags: 2sxc

I currently have DNN 7 installed and have been unable to get your module to work.

I do a typical module install of 2sic_2SexyContent_08.04.07_Install with apparently no issues.

When I drag the Content module to a pane there's an exception created in the log although the module does show up on the page.

I then click "Auto configure..." and then OK in the pop-up
It shows "installing Getting Started Templates" but then a pop-up shows error 500

The log shows:
"The given key was not present in the dictionary" and "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I checked github but couldn't find a resolution.

Is there an easy fix to this as I'd really like to get this installed. Heck, even if it's not easy, I still want to get it installed.

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a short video for you so you see what you *should* get: http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/moving-discussions-from-codeplex-to-stack-overflow

Here another guess

1. make sure your domain-names/paths are correct in DNN - these are portal settings and if something is wrong there, you will probably get funny redirects

Also: pls post some screenshots etc. - because that will help to understand which part is generating a 500

Note that it's also possible that whatever caused the initial error, did something which is hard to fix for inexperience users. So just to start, it's probably best to first create a new DNN, install 2sxc and when that works, figure out what is different in the two installs.

Comment: Did a clean install of 2sxcApp

Dropped module on page:
Pop-up with error: System.Exception: Module upgrade did not complete (read more). Click to complete:

Clicked "complete upgrade"
OK and restart

Checked Log:
Message:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
StackTrace:
   at ToSic.SexyContent.View.InitModuleActions() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\View.ascx.cs:line 160
   at ToSic.SexyContent.View.get_ModuleActions() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\View.ascx.cs:line 111

Comment: Removed module from page and then re-added.
No upgrade required this time...of course.

Hit browser F12 to follow install.
Clicked "Install Recommended...."

.....and it installed everything this time!?

Checked log again. Got 3 more General Exceptions but everything seems to work fine. I've played with a few apps without issue.

Sorry to be a bother. Pretty sure I did the same thing second time 'round as did the first.

Regardless....great app and appreciate your help!

Bob

Comment: And now I'll try to format this....Didn't seem to have an issue with the original post....

Comment: And now it's too late to edit.<br/><br/>Sorry for the mess

Comment: Yup everything's working fine. I've been playing with things with no issues. Still trying to figure out how some things work, but then that's what playing is for.  Thanks